# Can't disable Empty Selection in an IKImageBrowserView

Tags: objective-c, ikimagebrowserview

I have a browser view full of images - works great. However, I've unchecked 'allows empty selection' in IB, yet still when I click in a region not occupied by a thumbnail, the selection becomes nil. I would expect clicks outside a region not occupied by a thumbnail to be ignored, and the browser view to have its first object selected automatically on load. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered a workaround for this - do `[imageBrowser setAllowsEmptySelection: NO];` in code. Seemingly it doesn't work when called from IB? Strange, but an easy solution.